# What should we do when new users post questions as an answer?

Tags: support, answers, new-users, not-an-answer

[What](https://superuser.com/questions/860525/shortcut-key-for-toggling-yosemites-notification-center-between-today-and-no) should we do about stuff like Serge's answer to this question? On the one hand, his question seems similar too the one being asked and it would probably serve well as a comment or something similar, but he doesn't have enough reputation to post a comment.

Is this a situation to flag for a moderator? Copy paste the answer as a comment? Comment on the post and inform the user of their mistake?

Comment: Commenting is nice. flagging is fine - mods can convert a non answer  answer to a comment, or delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When any user posts a question as an answer, flag it for a moderator, marking it as "not an answer". Downvote if you so wish.

But this, this is just a question:

> Thanks Nelson for the code I have almost the same question than jimtut, but I try to "toggle" the view with a single script. [...] I tried different ways to "read" the value of radio group 1 of window "NotificationTableWindow" to define which pane is currently displayed, but nothing worked
>
> Thanks for your support